# Publish deploy ASP.NET Core MVC site on OVH domain

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm developed an ASP.NET Core MVC application, and I bought a domain name on OVH (I will call it example.fr for the example) and I tried to publish my web site asp.net core MVC on it using the FTP profile.

I have 3 different folder on my hosting server :
example.fr
[www.example.fr](http://www.example.fr)
www

So I targeted the folder www and a URL [www.example.fr](http://www.example.fr) in my FTPProfile before publishing.
I chose an Autnomous deploy in the publish settings with a win x64

After publishing I found all the files in the server browser , and when I try to execute my website I found a listing of files inside but no my application : do you how to solve that issue ?

[List of files found when executing my site in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q8XL.png)

I try to deploy my app on the domain I bought.
Do I need to use IIS or Azure or something else ? I'm quite lost frankly speaking :|

Comment: Does your hosting support ASP.NET applications?

Comment: https://www.meziantou.net/publishing-an-asp-net-core-website-to-a-linux-host.htm Found by googling `OVH run .net core`

Comment: I had a quick nose through the hosting plans on OVH's website and I don't see ASP.NET mentioned.

Comment: Please hover over the tags you have added. Some say explicitly _not_ to use them. Please remove those ones, and add appropriate tags instead.

Comment: Your hosting service has to support ASP.Net. It appears that OVH does not. Before you ask, we cannot provide recommendations for hosting services or other off-site resources here, which is clearly stated in the [help/on-topic] guidelines.